# Locate users/objects in AAD that aren’t synced to on-prem AD?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I tried Get-MsolUser -All -Synchronized:$false

But the results I’m getting show me users that are in fact synced to on-prem AD. What am I missing?

Comment: The parameter `-Synchronized` seems to be a switch parameter. This means with `-Synchronized:$false` you are acutally disabling this parameter just use `-Synchronized`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to find the list of Azure AD users using MSOL.

You can use `Get-MsolUser -All`---> (AzureAD user and SyncedUsers)
`Get-MsolUser -All -Synchronized:$false`  -> Azure AD users Excluding Synced users

[image]

Where Synchronized parameter use for getting the list of users which has Sync through AzureAD.

> **-Synchronized**
> Indicates that this cmdlet returns only users who are synchronized through Azure Active Directory Sync.
> Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0

For me I haven’t synced any user from on-prem AD to Azure Ad, so result is showing nothing.

[image]

There is another easier option to use it. Cloud only and on prem users have big difference - Its called Immutable ID

So `Get-MsolUser | where-Object {$_.ImmutableId -eq $null}` -> for On prem users

`Get-MsolUser | where-Object {$_.ImmutableId -ne $null}` for Azure AD users ( Cloud users)

Reference : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/how-to-list-users-synced-from-onprem-ad-and-cloud-only-users/m-p/498883